# Counting the number of term query matches in a boolean query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I could not find anything similar across stack overflow.

I'm building a content-based document-matching system with Elasticsearch where most data are keywords indexed.

Given a document in an index, I try to match as many as possible keyword fields in a boolean query in the same index. I'd like to return the number of term queries that matched per document alongside the BM25 score. Is there a way to do this?
So far I managed to parse the explain field and count how many score fields have been summed. But it doesn't sound ideal.

My DSL query:

```
query = {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "field1.keyword": {
                        "value": input["field1"],
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "field2.keyword": {
                        "value": input["field2"],
                    }
                }
            },
            ...

        ],
    }
}

res=client.search(index=index, query=query, explain=True)
```

and my way to retrieve the number of matched term queries:

```
len(res['hits']['hits'][0]['_explanation']['details'])
>>>8
len(res['hits']['hits'][9]['_explanation']['details'])
>>>5
```

Thanks for any help